# How stack multiple pivot tables based on multiple filters in EXCEL or R

Tags: r, excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table I created. This table is aggregating data by region and can be filtered by 2 categories (age, Income). How do I create a table such that each category combination (ex. Toddler & below 50% FPL, and Toddler, All incomes) are represented within each aggregation. So far, I am filtering for all combinations of Age and Income and just copying and pasting in a new spreadsheet. I linked a video where I show what I mean

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kUvDNxijXWZyJCCdVy398Gd0uq8vUFvY/view?usp=sharing

I am open to doing this in Excel or R.

Thank you very much for your help,
Rouzbeh

Comment: I see the video. But how granular or aggregated is your data? What are we seeing are this records or result from previous pivot tables?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do it in Excel you would require a third-party add-on or at least to code in VBA to do that.

In R you could find a solution. There is a similar question [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwPr5.png). That hasn't been marked as answered.

---

**R Solution**
In Base-R you can pivot using aggregate(). There are other function on other libraries like reshape2, data.table and dyplr. If you feel comfortable with those libraries, look for their aggregation or *group by* functions.

Sample Data: data=[image]

I do not know if you have a flag to determine if a subject is elegible. In that case I will use a custom aggregation. But if that's not the case you could use any of the traditional aggregation functions.

```
#Costume formula counting flags
 counEle <- function(x){
                    a=length(which(x=="x"))}
```

Then:

```
#Create all posibles combinations using Age and Income
combination = expand.grid(unlist(data["Age"]),unlist(data["Income"]))
#Eliminate duplicated combinations
combination=unique(combination)
#Create the loop that filters and aggregate for each combination.
for(i in 1:nrow(combination)){
    new_data=data[data$Age==combination[i,1] & data$Income==combination[i,2],]
    #Check that the data frame has more than 0 columns so it could be aggregated
    if(nrow(new_data)>0){
        #Aggregate the data with the values in place             
   print(try(aggregate(Eligibility~Age+Income+County,new_data,counEle)))
    }           
}
```

The total count is in the Eligibility columns which is the one we wanted to measure. This should output all possible combinations (mind you the error handler by the try(). If you want to ignore where the count is 0 you could add an additional step with a conditional to >0. Then write each result on a csv or use a library to write it on a excel tab.

[image]